# Angular 2 animation with async data

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, asynchronous

I have the following component which will simply fetch a dataset of skills containing a title and a percentage from my database.

My goal is to have the initial width value on each div be 0% and once the http request has come back and the correct information is retreived, set the correct percentage for each skill with an animation that goes from left to right (the divs will have a background-color so you should see its width grow, ex.: 0% ---> 95%).

I'm wondering what would be the best approach to accomplish this in a correct Angular 2 treatment. I know there's an animation property you can use on the component decorator but I'm not sure as to how to make it work with the async results coming in.

The most important thing about this question is how to handle the data that comes in through the async pipe in a way that I can show an animation for the percentage bump. Form 0 to whatever it will be. As it is now I immediately see the final result, however, an animation is never executed (and the anim is what I'm actually looking for, not just printing the final bar result).

I'm sure there are a few different ways to get this working, just confused as to which would be the best.

Here's my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { SkillsService } from './skills.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'skills',
  template: `
    <section class="skills">
      <div *ngFor="let skill of skillsService.skills$ | async">
        <div class="skills__bar" [style.width]="skill.percentage + '%'">
          <h3 class="skills__title">{{skill.title}}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  `,
})
export class SkillsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private skillsService: SkillsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.skillsService.fetchSkills()
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance, all!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS transition like so:

```js
//Demo purposes only.
$("#get-skills-btn").on("click", function() {
  var randomValue = Math.random();
  $(".skills__percentage").css("transform", "scaleX(" + randomValue + ")");
});
```

```css
.skills__bar {
  background-color: silver;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.skills__percentage {
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 300ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}
.skills__title {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="skills">
  <div>
    <div class="skills__bar">
      <div class="skills__percentage"></div>
      <h3 class="skills__title">{{skill.title}}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<button id="get-skills-btn">
  Fetch Data
</button>
```

For angular use something like this:

`[style.transform]="scaleX(skill.percentage/100)"`

Comment: Hey, Ricky! Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer. While this is a really rad way of solving the percentage bar with CSS, and I might actually use this approach for the style itself, it does not solve the most pressing issue, which is to handle the async data coming in. The async pipe handles the response (which is very small and therefore fast) in a way that I see the green portion immediately, with no animation. So I'm pretty much in the same place, seeing the desired final result, just not the animation to get there...

Answer (score 0):

With Angular 4.2+, we can do that using `@angular/animations`.

```
<div [@listParent]="len" class="list">
  <div *ngFor="let item of itemsAsync | async" [style.width]="item.val" class="item">
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

In component decorator, `listParent`animation is defined like:

```
animations: [
  trigger('listParent', [
    transition('* => *', [
      query(':enter', style({ width: 0 })),
      query(':enter', animate('1.6s', style({ width: '*'})))
    ])
  ])
```

`listParent`animation will be triggered whenever component property `len` changes.

In [this plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/CBaVvF/), try click `Get one` or `Get multiple` button.